# Django adding colon to the path out of nowhere

Tags: python, django

I have a pretty simple Django project based on the one from the tutorial that I am slowly morphing into my own app. It was working fine locally. I tried to deploy it to Heroku, so I made a few changes, but it was still working fine locally (I am still working on getting it to work on Heroku). But then I ran it once more and out of nowhere I am getting this error:

```
Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\cusack\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\website\\:\\index.html'
```

So it is adding `:\\` or `\\:` to the path for some reason. I have looked at settings.py, views.py, urls.py, and I can't find anywhere where I have told it to do this.
My `urls.py` file looks (partially) like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('images/random.png',views.my_image,name='randomImage'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

The main page and admin both give this error, but 'images/random.png' works just fine.
For the admin page, it is adding the extra `:\\` before `admin\\index.html`.

My `views.py` for this index is trivial:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

It happened when I was playing around with DEBUG and ALLOWED_HISTS, although changing them back to True and [] didn't seem to help.

Any idea where this could be coming from?

UPDATE: It appears the cause is from this line in setting TEMPLATES:
`'DIRS': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates'),`
It worked fine when it was:
`'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],`
but that doesn't work sometimes (I don't get it but sometimes it works, other times it says it doesn't know how to divide strings.) So I can't change it back and I can't use os.path.join for some reason because it mysteriously adds `:\\` for an unknown reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I replaced
`'DIRS': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates'),`
with
`'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`.
I'm still not sure why it was working for a while with the original code, and I am also not sure why the [ ] are needed.

Answer (score 0):

please check if in settings.py you have accidentally something like this DIRS list declaration left:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [":"],
        ...
```

if yes, change it to

```
        'DIRS': [],
```

Comment: Nope. I've looked everywhere for any stray occurrences of colons and I didn't see any.

Comment: It is added in the root of the path for html templates. Could also be at the end of PROJECT_ROOT or PROJECT_DIR. I am not sure which one is used for forming the template abs path

Comment: I don't set PROJECT_ROOT or PROJECT_DIR anywhere.